# Change the user in the Gihub Desktop Application for Mac

Tags: macos, git, github

I have recently bought a Mac from someone and am trying to switch the github account on the desktop application. It is showing all of the repositories/branches/etc. from their previous setup. I would like the profile picture and the repositories to be the ones from my account.

I successfully changed my email address in the terminal for my git config settings, and am able to make commits through terminal - However, when using the github client for mac, I am unable to see my profile. How do I make this change?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did you try GitHub > Preferences... > Accounts > Sign Out ?
And setting your account in the GitHub > Preferences... > Advanced > Git Config ?

Comment: Wow. I made this way harder on myself LOL. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Top Left corner of the screen, next to Mac symbol->Github->Preference!!